# Is it possible to use scanf on the same variable twice?

Tags: c

Is it possible to prompt the user to enter a char a second time and have the new char replace the original one? When I try this it will not allow me to enter a char the second time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    char x;

    printf("enter value: ");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    
    printf("enter value: ");
    scanf("%c", &x);
}
```

Comment: It is not allowing because you may be putting whitespace , try `scanf(" %c", &x)` note space before `%c`..

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible . Make sure to clear the buffer which might be left due to previous inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ 
    char x='p';

    printf("enter value: ");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("val is %c \n",x);
    printf("enter 2nd value: ");
    getchar();//flush the buffer
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("val is %c \n",x);
}
```

Problem was you was not clearing the buffer getchar function will clear it.

Comment: I am trying to understand why @kiran Biradar's solution **also works** ... see comment above to add space in the format: `" %c"` instead of `"%c"`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel A space in the format string matches any number of whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines) and is the preferred solution. The solution in this answer won't work if the user enters a character, presses the space key, and then presses Enter.

Comment: @Daniel adding the space before %c means that optional white space is skipped it can be space or new line.

Comment: @Daniel there are many questions similar to yours had already been asked.

Comment: `getchar();//flush the buffer` is overconfident - it assumes the following character is an `'\n'`.  Input is not certainly consumed until the end-of-line - that is - not "flushed".